# Existence of closed solution of a certain type of Poisson equations

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I want to check whether my numerical FEM solver is correct or not. So I seek a solution of 
\begin{equation}
-\Delta u(x,y)=f(x,y) \text{ on } [-1,1]\times[-1,1]\\
u(-1,y)=1\\
u(x,y)=0\text{ on other boundary} 
\end{equation}
In other words, the boundary value is 1 when $x=-1$ and zero otherwise.

Is there any $f$ so that a closed form of $u$ exists for such equations? Or is there another way to check my FEM solver is correct? Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the easiest way how to check if your solver is correct is to pick a solution $u$ and then compute the boundary conditions and the right hand side $f$. I. e. pick your favourite $u$, find the values on boundaries and set $f = -\Delta u$. Constant or linear $u$ might be a good first choice.

Your boundary conditions are a bit problematic because of the corners in which is the jump between $u=0$ and $u=1$. This means that $u \notin H^{\frac 1 2}(\partial \Omega)$ and the standard variational formulation will fail to apply. Intuitively, your boundary conditions force the solution to have infinite gradient in the two corners.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to compute finite difference and then compare with f. lol